# Что записать в блок catch (err)?

Tags: javascript

Всем добра.
Есть некий скрипт, который запускается через Tampermonkey на некотором сайте. Порой он может проработать до 24 часов без нареканий. Порой, останавливается через полчаса после запуска. 
Посоветовали затолкать код скрипта в конструкцию типа:

```
try {
// код ...
} catch (err) {
// обработка ошибки
}
```

Я не знаю почему скрипт останавливается и мне требуется узнать. Может это какая-то ошибка в самом скрипте, а может это ошибка сайта - я не знаю.
Подскажите, что писать в блоке catch для моей ситуации

Comment: `console.log(err)` Например. Ну и в любом случае ты должен видеть ошибки в консоли браузера

Comment: Должен, но не вижу.

Comment: очевидно тогда _ошибок_ нет

Comment: "Должен, но не вижу" -  ну так подождать нужно до возникновения нареканий

Comment: если есть доступ к серверу, отправьте данные об ошибке аяксом, например....

Comment: Может он выполнил возложенную на него функцию :)

Comment: Его функция не имеет финиша)

Answer (score 1):

```
console.error(err)
```

Предназначен для печати ошибок :)

Или можете записать в localstorage:

```
localStorage.setItem("error", JSON.stringify(err));
```

Это позволит Вам читать данные с клиентов даже через несколько дней

можно еще отправить AJAX запрос на сервер с текстом ошибки а также будет полезным отправить максимум данных о клиенте.